# JQuery Ajax , why in success i have error why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ajaxq

Why in success I have error?

```
$('#ck').click(function() {
  var StudentData = [{
    'Name': 'Ali',
    'Age': 27
  }, {
    'Name': 'Sam',
    'Age': 32
  }];

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/StudentInfo",
    data: JSON.stringify(StudentData),
    ...
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response[0].Name);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error");
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Your question is a mess. Please take a look at http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour and take some time before re-writing your question.

Comment: What error?  What are you talking about?  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here.  *Explain the problem.*

Comment: alert(response[0].Name); // error here ... and how i can get value??!

Comment: This tells us absolutely nothing. At least add the error you see.

Comment: My guess is response isn't an array

Comment: return // undefined 
@MasterYoda

Comment: @mahmodnasser Okay, have you specified that the dataType for the response should be json? output the response object using `console.log(response);` and tell us what it says please.

Comment: We need to see what you're returning from server. It might be response.Name, response.Students[0].Name, etc, whatever. You didn't provide enough details.

Comment: @David , everything is good but i'm asked why return (undefined) in alert??! this is my problem i need to return value , can you help me?

Comment: @mahmodnasser: Well, what is `response`?  Not what do you *assume* it is, not what do you *want* it to be, but when you actually debug this what *is it*?  Clearly the value you're looking for isn't defined.  So... Either look for a value that *is* defined, or *define* the value.

Comment: im forget add this
//
public JsonResult StudentInfo(List<object> StudentData)
        {
            return Json(StudentData);
        }
***********************
just i need access to value ? how i can do that?? anyway?

Comment: @mahmodnasser: `List<object> StudentData` - And why would you expect `object` to have a property called `Name`?  I certainly don't see one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object  Again, and I can't stress this enough, what specifically happens when you *debug your code*?  What does `StudentData` contain in your server-side code?  What does `response` contain in your client-side code?  Debugging should be your ***first*** step, we shouldn't have to *remind* you to do it.

Comment: in this example that is very simple but, i don't know why nothing is return just return undefined , // in debug no problem no error  ,
***
anyone can help me to get any value in this example i need to way to access to any value , i'm new in Jqery Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an excessively lengthy comment thread above, you claim to have this server-side code:

```
public JsonResult StudentInfo(List<object> StudentData)
{
    return Json(StudentData);
}
```

So, you're returning a `List<object>` to your client-side code.  Then in your client-side code you try to access a property on an element in that list:

```
success: function (response) {
    alert(response[0].Name);
}
```

Well, to put is simply, [`object` doesn't contain a property called `Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object).  It never has, and it probably never will.  So you can't access a property that *doesn't exist*.  Hence, it's `undefined` in JavaScript.

It *looks like* you meant to define a class for your objects.  Something as simple as this:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use *that* class in your action method:

```
public JsonResult StudentInfo(List<Student> StudentData)
{
    return Json(StudentData);
}
```

Since `Student` *does* have a property called `Name`, you can use that property in your client-side code.

Comment: thanks you so much it's work

Comment: ****this not work
 public JsonResult StudentInfo(List<object> StudentData)
{
    return Json(StudentData);
}
****this work
public JsonResult StudentInfo(List<Student> StudentData)
{
    return Json(StudentData);
}
**** Thanks you